# Scipy fmin argument passing

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

so I'm just a bit confused as to how scipy.optimize.fmin takes arguments

say I have two functions:

```
def func_1(x, y):
   return (x*x) + (y*y)

def func_2(x, y, a):
   return ((x-a)*(x-a)) + ((y-a) *(y-a))
```

in func_1 I simply want the min values for x and y, and in func_2 I'd ideally like to pass a value for a , and then find the min vals for x and y. I've read some of the other questions in regard to this, and am still a bit confused.

Attempts to call : `fmin(fund_1, [1,1])` results in :  `fmin() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change the signature of `func_1` and `func_2` to something like:

```
def func_1(t):
   x,y=t
   return (x*x) + (y*y)

def func_2(t, a):
   x,y=t
   return ((x-a)*(x-a)) + ((y-a) *(y-a))
```

In the first case, use

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
from numpy import array
fmin(func_1,array([1,1]))
```

In the second case, you must pass to `fmin` the argument `args=(a,)`. It will do exactly what you describe,

```
fmin(func_2,array([1,1]),args=(3,))
```

Comment: And the first? I keep attempting to pass: fmin(func_1, [1,1]) and receive  fmin() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given). This is very confusing to me

Comment: Ahhh, ok, so fmin optimizes of a vector? I.E any param I am attempting to solve for must be contained in an array?

Comment: kind of, yes. the first argument of `func_1/func_2`, which above is `t`, is a vector quantity. All the rest appearing in `func_2` signature, which in this case is simply `a`, are additional arguments that must be passed to `fmin` through `args=(a,)` as a tuple.

Comment: Many, many thanks. Last question on this I promise. So, I got the func_1 to run, but x and y should both be 0, however I get returned:  [ -2.10235293e-05   2.54845649e-05], and when I proceed to call func_1 on these values, I do not receive 0 as the min of fund_1 as expected. Is this an error on my end, or scipy's?

Comment: This is a numerical solution, and is then affected by numerical error. So it's nobody's fault. If you You can ask `fmin` for better numerical precision, by changing the values of `xtol` and `ftol`. See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html).

Comment: The thanks I give you cannot be measured in accepted answers. Thank you very, very, (and one more time) very much.

Comment: Well, you can upvote this answer if you want. And you may want to review your other questions. All others do not have an accepted answer.